# What is the directory "..." when using git?

Tags: git

During a "git pull" operation, I get a report about objects in a "..." directory. What is this directory ? I'm surprised because when trying "ls -l ..." in a shell, the response is "No such file or directory". There is obviously a difference to the git syntax. What is this difference ?

Here is an exemple of such an output:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 69, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (69/69), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
remote: Total 47 (delta 27), reused 26 (delta 6), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (47/47), done.
From https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex
   dba88acaba..27c32529ab  master     -> origin/master
Updating dba88acaba..27c32529ab
Fast-forward
 .../java/org/basex/io/parse/json/JsonBasicConverter.java     |  4 +---
 basex-core/src/main/java/org/basex/query/func/db/DbNew.java  |  4 ++--
 .../main/java/org/basex/query/func/fn/FnAnalyzeString.java   | 12 ++++++------
 basex-core/src/test/java/org/basex/query/expr/MixedTest.java |  9 +++++++++
 4 files changed, 18 insertions(+), 11 deletions(-)
```

Comment: Can you show us the output you're seeing by editing your question to include a code block with the appropriate text?

Comment: Not directly an answer to your Q; you got that below. However, you wrote that  *ls -l does not show...*. In UNIX, files with names starting with a dot are called *hidden* files. To include them in an *ls* listing, you need to add the "a" option, e.g. *ls -la*

Answer (score 3):

It's a truncated path.

Consider the full path of two of the files:

```
basex-core/src/main/java/org/basex/io/parse/json/JsonBasicConverter.java
basex-core/src/main/java/org/basex/query/func/db/DbNew.java
```

One path is simply too long to display, so it is truncated. However, cutting of the end is not a sensible choice for paths, because the most valuable information is towards the end. Hence, the start is cut off.